# ASP.NET MVC with EF page loses model data after post via return View()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework from a book, and this example below is a "Delete" view that lists a car's details as a confirmation page for user to delete.

Once Delete link is clicked, the form is posted to the Delete action again that binds the Id and Timestamp then attempts to delete. If deletion fails due to exception, an error is added to ModelState, and the user is presented with the same Delete view displaying the error.

Delete post action: (the get version, omitted here, simply retrieves model object via Id and displays first image below)

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete([Bind(Include = "Id,Timestamp")] Inventory inventory)
        {
            
            try
            {
                _repo.Delete(inventory);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $@"Unable to delete record. Another user updated the record. {ex.Message}");
                return View(inventory);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $@"Unable to delete record: {ex.Message}");
                return View(inventory);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

[image]

The problem is that if a delete operation does fail due to exception, the page loses the model data (inventory) even though it was passed again via return `View(inventory)`

How do I show the error page while retaining the model data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding just the ID and the Timestamp properties. So the Inventory object passed to your post action contains only those values.
Of course, when the code returns that same object your view is not able to show the other properties.

You can simply remove the [Bind attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.bindattribute) and you should get the whole inventory data in your post action, or probably a better alternative, continue to use the Bind attribute but, in case of exceptions, reload the Inventory object before returning it to your View.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I'm new at this, thought the "inventory" object from the previous confirmation page would still persist to the next page. Didn't realize it has to get re-constructed from scratch.